# How does a turbopump work

Tags: turbopump

I am a kid pursuing a career in propulsion, and I was wondering, "how does a  turbopump work?" I would really appreciate a detailed explanation.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have questions that the Wikipedia article does not address? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbopump

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks, I didn't think of that! (I am only in middle school)

Comment: After reading the article, come back if you have specific questions!

Comment: @OrganicMarble why, when the pump spins, does the fuel not explode? when I spin something, usually there is friction, which causes heat, so why does the fuel not combust in the turbopump?

Comment: So the thing to do is, [edit] your question and change it to ask this instead of the original, too general question. That way it will show up in the site's list of questions and possibly attract someone to answer it.  The rules for asking questions here can seem somewhat strict but they help maintain a well-ordered site.

Comment: @Random9 The fuel needs an oxidizer to explode. One of the design parts of a rocket engine is keeping the fuel and oxidizer very carefully separated until you want them to mix in the combustion chamber.

Comment: A4 / V2 Rocket in detail: Turbopump https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgiMu8A3pi0